# CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension error (but php_intl is installed and activated) [ZendServer 6.3]

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, zend-server-ce

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
[..]
```

but... php_int is enabled

```
Internationalization support    enabled
version                         1.1.0
ICU version                     4.4.2
ICU Data version                4.4.2

Directive               Local Value      Master Value
intl.default_locale     pl_PL            pl_PL
intl.error_level        1                1
intl.use_exceptions     0                0
```

I have no idea why the composer cannot see installed and working php_int extension. Any clue?

PHP Version 5.5.7 (CGI/FastCGI), Windows.

Zend Server Version: 6.3.0

Comment: As in 99% of these cases there's probably a separate `.ini` for the CLI where the extension is not being included, check `php --ini`

Comment: You have partly right! This error was caused by configuration of the `PATH variable` in environment variables. After checking `php --ini` (thank you for this hint!) I discovered that php recognizes only first localization of the .ini and it was an old, an unused one. **Zend Server ignoring this path and uses its own.**

Comment: (is why seemingly, everything was ok)